# Reactjs X Vitejs multi-page app fallback to the main entry when I reload a nested route

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have created a multi-page app using Reactjs and Vitejs, the app have two entry points - main and secondary entry points. The navigation on both apps work as expected. When I navigate to the secondary app `using http://localhost:3000/secondary/`, it renders the homepage even if I reload the page.

However, when I navigate to a nested route on the secondary app e.g `http://localhost:3000/secondary/dashboard` - it renders the dashboard component as expected but when I reload the dashboard page, the app fallback to the main entry(`index.html`) instead of sticking to the `secondary/index.html` entry - so I get page not found error.

All hacks I tried didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is now fixed